# Tkinter Text Scrollbar goes Too Far

Tags: python, tkinter

I was wondering why my `scrollbar` goes too far for my `Tkinter` `Text` `widget`. I have a bottom label which is supposed to fill up all the space below, yet somehow the `scrollbar` reaches beyond the `label` to the end. I am not sure exactly which `widget` is causing this.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog

class TextLineNumbers(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.textwidget = None

    def attach(self, text_widget):
        self.textwidget = text_widget

    def redraw(self, *args):
        '''redraw line numbers'''
        self.delete("all")

        i = self.textwidget.index("@0,0")
        while True:
            dline= self.textwidget.dlineinfo(i)
            if dline is None: break
            y = dline[1]
            linenum = str(i).split(".")[0]
            self.create_text(5,y,anchor="nw", text=linenum)
            i = self.textwidget.index("%s+1line" % i)

class CustomText(tk.Text): 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.tk.eval('''
            proc widget_proxy {widget widget_command args} {

                # call the real tk widget command with the real args
                set result [uplevel [linsert $args 0 $widget_command]]

                # generate the event for certain types of commands
                if {([lindex $args 0] in {insert replace delete}) ||
                    ([lrange $args 0 2] == {mark set insert}) || 
                    ([lrange $args 0 1] == {xview moveto}) ||
                    ([lrange $args 0 1] == {xview scroll}) ||
                    ([lrange $args 0 1] == {yview moveto}) ||
                    ([lrange $args 0 1] == {yview scroll})} {

                    event generate  $widget <<Change>> -when tail
                }

                # return the result from the real widget command
                return $result
            }
            ''')
        self.tk.eval('''
            rename {widget} _{widget}
            interp alias {{}} ::{widget} {{}} widget_proxy {widget} _{widget}
        '''.format(widget=str(self)))

        self.comment = False

class Window(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.bottomLabel()
        self.createtext()

    def createtext(self):
        self.text = CustomText(self, bd=0)  

        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.vsb.configure(command=self.text.yview)

        self.linenumbers = TextLineNumbers(self, width=55)
        self.linenumbers.attach(self.text)

        self.vsb.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        self.linenumbers.pack(side="left", fill="y")
        self.text.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.text.bind("<<Change>>", self._on_change)
        self.text.bind("<Configure>", self._on_change)

    def bottomLabel(self):
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Lorem ipsum", anchor=tk.W)
        self.label.pack(fill=tk.X, side=tk.BOTTOM)

    def _on_change(self, event):
        self.linenumbers.redraw()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Window")
    window = Window(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't give the scrollbar an explicit parent, so its parent will be the root window. The fix is pretty simple: make sure it has the same parent as the text widget:

```
self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
```

Answer (score 2):

This will fix your problem:

Change
`self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(orient=tk.VERTICAL)`

to

EDIT:

`self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(master=self, orient=tk.VERTICAL)`

Comment: This worked like a charm. Could u please explain why this worked?

Comment: Well just remember to state a parent if given. Even if you know u don't need one. Seems like the `Frame` was set as the parent of your scrollbar. Also if you approach a problem like this, looking at the sourcecode is a good start. In your case the first sentence after `__init__` of Scrollbar was `"""Construct a scrollbar widget with the parent MASTER.`

Comment: By making the scrollbar a child of the text widget, the scrollbar will appear _inside_ the borders of the text widget. If you have characters in the text widget that extend to the right margin, they will be obscured by the scrollbar. Type a really long line into the widget and you can see that effect.